# How to use Collections.binarySearch() in a CodenameOne project

Tags: codenameone

I am used to being able to perform a binary search of a *sorted* list of, say, `String`s or `Integer`s, with code along the lines of:

```
Vector<String> vstr = new Vector<String>();
//  etc...
int index = Collections.binarySearch (vstr,  "abcd");
```

I'm not clear on how codenameone handles standard java methods and classes, but it looks like this could be fixed easily if classes like `Integer` and `String` (or the codenameone versions of these) implemented the `Comparable` interface.

Edit: I now see that code along the lines of the following will do  the job.

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(vstr, "abcd", new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
        return object1.compareTo(object2);
    }
});
```

Adding the Comparable interface (to the various primitive "wrappers") would also would also make it easier to use `Collections.sort` (another very useful method :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also sort with a comparator but I agree, this is one of the important enhancements we need to provide in the native VM's on the various platforms personally [this is my biggest peeve in our current VM](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1783).

Can you file an RFE on that and mention it as a comment in the `Number` issue?

If we are doing that change might as well do both.

Comment: I added a comment to the `Number` issue.  I'm new to Github and wasn't sure about where/how to mention the need for `String` to also be comparable, so apologies if I muddied things!

Comment: Thanks, that's good. I was hoping to get this out before 3.6 but we'll probably do it early in the 3.7 cycle.